# What is the shortest LOOP program that outputs 2016?

Tags: atomic-code-golf

### LOOP

This challenge is based around a modified version of the programming language [LOOP](http://www.eugenkiss.com/projects/lgw/).

A program may be of any of the following forms:

- `P;Q`, where `P` and `Q` are subprograms

  - Subprogram P is executed, then subprogram Q is executed.
- `x++`, where `x` is a variable

  - Variable names are the letter `x` followed by a whole number (`0`, `1`, `2`, etc.). The value of variable x is incremented and assigned to variable x.
- `x:=y`, where `x` and `y` are variables

  - The value of variable y is assigned to variable x
- `LOOP x DO P END`, where `x` is a variable, and `P` is a subprogram

  - Subprogram P is executed a number of times equal to the value of x at the start of the loop. If the value of x changes during the loop, the number of iterations does not change.

Spaces and newlines may be inserted anywhere.

For this challenge, you may not use constants.

For example, the code
   `LOOP x1 DO x2 := x2 + 1; LOOP x2 DO x1++ END END`
will set `x1` to the `x1`<sup>th</sup> triangle number, by adding 1, then 2 etc.

### Task

All variables are initialized to 0. The output of the program is the final value of x0, and the length of a program is the total count of increment/decrement/assignment/loop. The goal is to output 2016 with a program that is as short as possible.

[Here](https://github.com/KSFTmh/PPCGLOOP/blob/master/interpreter.py) is an interpreter for the modified language used in this challenge.

Comment: The LOOP interpreter you linked to doesn't seem to support the `++` notation.  Do you know of one that does?

Comment: @PhiNotPi I'll work on writing one.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened to the comment I put here. It was this: "How is this closed with three downvotes and no comments? The challenge should be self-contained and have the LOOP specification, but I think it's very clear what the challenge is--write a LOOP program that sets a variable to 2016 in as few lines as you can."

Comment: @KSFT I deleted the comment. The post was previously closed as unclear but was reopened, so the comment saying that it's not unclear was no longer relevant.

Comment: @AlexA. It's still relevant to the two people who have still downvoted it.

Comment: @KSFT I downvoted it because 1.) it's language-specific, 2.) an interpreter that supports the necessary operations does not yet seem to exist, 3.) I find the task uninteresting. I would imagine that the one other downvoter (as of this writing) felt the same way.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because answers cannot be verified as correct without a working interpreter that supports all necessary operators.

Comment: @AlexA. I've attempted to write an interpreter, and I put a link to it in the question. Can we reopen it now?

Comment: The interpreter doesn't continue after an END correctly. Also I have a 99 byte answer: `x1++;x1++;x1++;x1++;LOOPx1DOLOOPx1DOx2++;x2++;LOOPx1DOx3++ENDENDEND;x3--;LOOPx2DOLOOPx3DOx0++ENDEND`.

Comment: I think this is not off-topic, but unclear. Nowhere in the description says that `<var> := <var> + <var>` syntax is allowed, but the example program includes it.

Answer (score 1):

## Naive attempt, 15 statements

This uses the factorization of 2016 into `2^5*3^2*7`.

```
x1++;
x1++;
x2:=x1;
x2++;
x3:=x2+x2;
x3++;
LOOP x1 DO
LOOP x1 DO
LOOP x1 DO
LOOP x1 DO
LOOP x1 DO
LOOP x2 DO
LOOP x2 DO
LOOP x3 DO
x0++
END
END
END
END
END
END
END
END
```

I've gotten this to run on the provided interpreter by replacing things like `x1++;` with `x1:=x1+1;`, although I did not use "strict mode."

Comment: The linked interpreter doesn't seem to like `x3:=x2+x2;` otherwise I would suggest using `x2:=x3+x1;` to save you from having to loop twice over `x2`.